# How to delete the _MEI file in C:\Windows\Temp generated by running the exe program packaged by python

Tags: memory-management, permissions, pyinstaller, python-3.7, data-cleaning

I run multiple python-encapsulated exe programs on the server. After the environment resources of each program are released, there are about 20 G, which causes the C drive to be full. I try to delete it, but the result fails. I hope:

1. Able to regularly delete the generated _MEI temporary files every day
2. Or reduce the memory threshold generated by temporary files to allow more space on the C drive

I run multiple python-encapsulated exe programs on the server. After the environmental resources of each program are released, there are about 20 G, which causes the C disk to be full. I try to delete it, but the result fails. The following are the methods I have tried :

1. Right-click to open the properties of the Temp folder, and modify the user's full control attribute of the folder, but it still cannot be deleted
2. Give anaconda full control authority, and then use python's os.chmod command to modify the permission of the file to be deleted, try to use the shutil.rmtree command to delete the file, and report an error: access to the file is denied.
3. Open gepedit.msc via regit Enable user control: run all administrators in admin approval mode. Still unresponsive when deleting folders manually
   The above methods have been tried to run as an administrator when deleting, but they can’t be deleted.